# Parsing query result string from psycopg2 with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am interacting with a custom PSQL engine which supports complex types like arrays or dictionaries.

The problem is that, when using `psycopg2` to query those, everything is returned as a string.

For example, an array might be returned like this as a string:

```
"{0.04286956042051315,-0.40017685294151306,-0.027973683550953865,0.4197809100151062,0.4434552788734436,0.774429440498352,-0.3255774676799774,0.5705142021179199}"
```

And same for arbitrarily nested/complex types representing dict structures:

```
"""[key1 -> "[subkey1 -> "(2019-05-05 14:34:22.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,status1)"]"]"""
```

I am trying to cast all that into Python types. I have found a way to do it easily in the first case when it's just an array with:

```
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.new_array_type(
        (my_oid,), 'ARR[]', psycopg2.NUMBER))
```

But in the second case for dictionaries I am not sure what the best way is to go about it. I was thinking to use `psycopg2`'s `new_type` function, but writing the UDF for this is a bit cumbersome since the output seems custom and does not seem to be parsable with `ast.literal_eval`

Is there a better way to go about this to parse this string, or is writing a custom parser for this string format?